# Why doesn't this jQuery.post work with Perl CGI?

Tags: jquery, perl, cgi

I'm trying to figure out why I'm not seeing params with $.post("/url/", {wtf: 2}).

I'm using this perl:

```
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header("text/javascript");
print "'no'";

use Data::Dumper;
warn Dumper({ (map {$_=>$cgi->param($_ )} $cgi->param), postdata=>$cgi->param("POSTDATA") });
```

When I issue a $.get("/url", {wtf: 2}), I get the results I expect and find
wtf is 2 in the logs.  When I use $.post("/url/", {wtf: 2}), I don't seem
to get any params at all (just a $VAR1 = { postdata=>undef } in the logs).

What am I missing?

Firebug reveals that: Transfer-Encoding  is "chunked" and Content-Type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8".  Further, the Post tab seems to show the arguments in the request, but no joy from CGI.

Comment: I should say that I've tried with various versions of jquery and get the same results ... 1.1.4, 1.2.2, and 1.3.2.

Comment: Mantra: use warnings is *more important* than use strict.

Comment: I use warnings while I'm still writing, but rarely leave it on for production code.

Comment: The netcat idea (I actually used tcpdump) showed them coming in as params like they should.  Then I noticed that I had shot myself in the foot with a security feature that blocks unwanted params that was blocking the params I wanted.  So basically I'm dumb.

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got access to a linux box, you could set up 'nc' (netcat) to listen on port 80 and see the raw requests you're receiving.

I suspect it's a server-side problem though. Perhaps some Apache configuration is interfering? Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 4):

Could be that your results are coming back neither application/x-www-form-urlencoded nor multipart/form-data. [CGI doc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#HANDLING_NON-URLENCODED_ARGUMENTS) has this to say about it:

> If POSTed data is not of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, then the POSTed data will not be processed, but instead be returned as-is in a parameter named POSTDATA. To retrieve it, use code like this:

```
    my $data = $query->param('POSTDATA');
```

Comment: POSTDATA seems to be empty also.

Comment: Are you testing the result of the map or are you testing $cgi->param("POSTDATA") itself? If the value of POSTDATA is 'a=1&b=2&c=-3', that isn't going to have any resolution in the name-value pairs of the query object.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, though I was using CGI::Lite instead.

Turns out the .post function in jquery seems to override the content type of the form, even if it has been set explicitly. A simple 'ngrep' revealed it to always come through as:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Problem was, the CGI::Lite module was expecting an *exact* match of only 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' (ie without the charset bit).

Changing this line of code from an exact match to a regular expression match in CGI/Lite.pm made things work for me:

```
#($content_type eq 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')) {
($content_type =~  /application\/x-www-form-urlencoded/)) {
```